# ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException

Tags: java, spring, localization

I'm instantiating a `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` like the following as Spring bean.

```
<bean id="resourceBundleMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="locale/messages"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

And then use it in my service bean like that:

```
@Qualifier("resourceBundleMessageSource")
private final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
public MyClassName(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource) {
    this.messageSource = messageSource;
}

public void myMethod() {
    String message = messageSource.getMessage("notification.sample", null, getUsersLocale(guest));
    // (...)
}
```

And my `resources/locale/messages_en.properties` looks like the following line:

```
notification.sample: This is a sample translation.
```

But then it throws the following exception:

```
[web.1]: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'notification.sample' for locale 'en'.] with root cause
[web.1]: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'notification.sample' for locale 'en'.
[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:155)
[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
// (...)
```

Comment: is your message bundle on the classpath?

Comment: Yes it is in the classpath.

Comment: On a side note are you noticing that the official spring documentation is unavailable at the moment?  I'm trying to do some research but cannot access the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `@Autowired` annotation to the field, instead of the constructor.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("resourceBundleMessageSource")
private final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;


public MyClassName() {

}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything.